# NSMutableAttributedString to an array

Tags: arrays, nsmutableattributedstring, strikethrough

The desired thing here is to strikethrough a task in a tableview by using the NSMutableAttributedString. The issue is that I don't know how to apply this effect on the array / identify the task in the array.

Everything works smooth but I do not know how to apply the last line in a correct way.

//name.attributedText = attributeString;

```
import RealmSwift
import Foundation
import Realm


class Task: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    @objc dynamic var isFinished = false



    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    convenience init(id: String, name: String, isFinished: Bool) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.isFinished = isFinished
    }


var realm: Realm!
    var taskArray: Results<Task>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.realm = try! Realm()
        self.taskArray = realm.objects(Task.self)

    }


    func saveAction(name: String) {
        let task = Task(id: UUID().uuidString, name: name, isFinished: false)
        try! self.realm.write {
            self.realm.add(task)
        }
        taskTableView.reloadData()
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! UITableViewCell
        let task = taskArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = task.name

        let taskSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 20, height: 20))
        taskSwitch.isOn = false
        taskSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateLabel(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        cell.accessoryView = taskSwitch
        let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: task.name!)
        if taskSwitch.isOn == true {
            attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
            //name.attributedText = attributeString;
     }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: It's missing `cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedString`.

Comment: @Larme, it is not working. The labels are not being strikethroughed. I believe that the "task" or the "taskArray" must be attributed?

Comment: It doesn’t have to. But do you pass in the if taskSwitch.isOn?

Comment: You were right, thank you! Encountered other issues but this one is fixed!